# Selectedindex change for combobox is not working using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling, selectedindexchanged

In my code I get city name and population number from a large .xls file.I set these values in datagridview table in window form application. Then I extract only city name and set it to the 1st Combobox. The fisrt combobox item looks like this-

```
    Flensburg
    Kiel
    Lübeck
```

Then I make a text file which contain the city name and interesting place list of that cilty. My txt file look like this.

```
Flensburg;Nordertor;Naval Academy Mürwik;Flensburg Firth
Kiel;Laboe Naval Memorial;Zoological Museum of Kiel University;Kieler    Förde;German submarine U-995;Sparkassen-Arena;Aquarium GEOMAR;Old Botanical Garden, Kiel;Holstein-Stadion;Botanischer Garten der Christian-Albrechts-Universität zu Kiel;Schwentine;Schulensee;Lanker See;Postsee;Rosensee
Lübeck;Holstentor;St. Mary's Church, Lübeck;Passat (ship);Burgtor;Lübeck Museum of Theatre Puppets;Trave;St. Catherine's Church, Lübeck;Lübeck Cathedral;St. Anne's Museum Quarter, Lübeck;Behnhaus;Behnhaus;Theater Lübeck;Ratzeburger See;Bucu;Hemmelsdorfer See;Stadion an der Lohmühle;Dassower See
```

Now I implement a dictionary to change the 2nd combobox value according to the first combobox. such as when first combobox show Flensburg, it will show all the places of Flensburg on 2nd combobox. However the code was perfect until it was implemnted in the main Form, that is Form1.cs. But Now I try to write it with another class with separate method. So Now I am facing problem because I cannot fix the objectsender and evetaverage problem and pass it in the Form1.cs.

My code for Data Class is-

```
       namespace POIList
        {
                public class POI
                {

                    public static ComboBox Combo_list1 = new ComboBox();
                    public static ComboBox Combo_list2 = new ComboBox();
                    public static DataGridView dataTable = new DataGridView();
                    Dictionary<string, List<string>> poi = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

                    public void List()
                    {

                        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
                        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
                        string SavedfileName = "POI_list.json";
                        var Saving_path = Path.Combine(folderName, SavedfileName);

                        string fileName = "Zensus_Gemeinden_org.xlsx";
                        var path = Path.Combine(startPath, fileName);

                        String name = "Gemeinden_31.12.2011_Vergleich";
                        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                       path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select [3] as City,[4] as Population, * From [" + name + "$D7:E11300] Where [4] > 10000", con);
                        con.Open();

                        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                        DataTable data = new DataTable();

                        sda.Fill(data);
                        dataTable.DataSource = data;

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Combo_list1.Items.Add(data.Rows[i]["City"]);
                        }
                        string Place_Json = "Place_List:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
                        File.WriteAllText(Saving_path, Place_Json);

                        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("POIList.txt"))
                        {
                            string[] parts = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            poi.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());
                            poi[parts[0]] = new List<string>(parts.Skip(1));


                        }

                    }

                   public void Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (Combo_list1.SelectedItem != null)
                        {
                            string txt = Combo_list1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                            if (poi.ContainsKey(txt))
                            {
                                List<string> points = poi[txt];
                                Combo_list2.Items.Clear();
                                Combo_list2.Items.AddRange(points.ToArray());

                            }
                        }
                    }



                }
            }
```

And Form1.cs is

```
 namespace TouristPlace
  {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        POI.Combo_list1 = comboBox1;
        POI.dataTable = dataGridView1;

        POI poi1 =new POI();
        poi1.List();

        POI poi2 = new POI();
        //poi2.Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public string ComboText1
    {
        get { return comboBox1.Text; }
        set { comboBox1.Text = value; }
    }
    public string ComboText2
    {
        get { return comboBox2.Text; }
        set { comboBox2.Text = value; }
    }
```

Comment: (not an answer to your question) I wouldn't put a reference to a ComboBox or DataGrid in a "data class", especially not a static one. One day this code will bite back.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can't see where you assign the callback to `Combo_list1.SelectedIndexChanged` event. Maybe this is the issue.

Try adding:

```
Combo_list1.SelectedIndexChanged += Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

in your POI class, for example in List() function. Make sure that the List() function is called only once, otherwise the callback will bel called multiple times. If you can't be sure, you can do in this way:

```
Combo_list1.SelectedIndexChanged -= Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged;
Combo_list1.SelectedIndexChanged += Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Anyway, as someone else told you in the OP, you should move the ComboBox inside the form, it's not safe to leave them in a data class.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your answer. I mean where can I add Combo_list1.SelectedIndexChanged += Combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged; Also If I make the code static then dictionary was not working.

Comment: That's ok, but why you made the ComboBox static? I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am quite new handling this situation. Can you please tell me what should I do to make it work perfectly.

Comment: I modified my answer, this should fix your combo behavior!